# Using cumprod in group_by date

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the cumprod of the variable E_Return using the following code:

```r
CombData <- CombData %>%
  group_by(Date, E_P) %>%
  mutate(E_Return = cumprod(1+mean(ExReturn)))
```

However this does not yield the expected output. I would like my data to like that attached below:

```
    Date    ExRet   E_P E_Return    Expected_output
241 31-03-2010  0.089056627 5b  1.053187859 1.053187859
242 31-03-2010  0.098784758 5b  1.053187859 1.053187859
243 31-03-2010  -0.017049153    5b  1.053187859 1.053187859
244 31-03-2010  0.095247063 5b  1.053187859 1.053187859
245 31-03-2010  -0.0001 5b  1.053187859 1.053187859
246 31-03-2010  0.108514232 5w  1.072455783 1.072455783
247 31-03-2010  0.158042269 5w  1.072455783 1.072455783
248 31-03-2010  0.042564345 5w  1.072455783 1.072455783
249 31-03-2010  0.087244029 5w  1.072455783 1.072455783
250 31-03-2010  -0.034085962    5w  1.072455783 1.072455783
... 31-03-2010  0.165809091 NA  1.080485212 1.080485212
... 31-03-2010  0.102464103 NA  1.080485212 1.080485212 
... 31-03-2010  -0.026817557    NA  1.080485212 1.080485212
361 30-04-2010  0.086183186 5b  1.050524434 1.10639958
362 30-04-2010  0.113567118 5b  1.050524434 1.10639958
363 30-04-2010  0.103348276 5b  1.050524434 1.10639958
364 30-04-2010  -0.034222563    5b  1.050524434 1.10639958
365 30-04-2010  -0.016253846    5b  1.050524434 1.10639958
366 30-04-2010  -0.098072973    5w  1.026629717 1.101014976
367 30-04-2010  0.022235025 5w  1.026629717 1.101014976
368 30-04-2010  0.080067015 5w  1.026629717 1.101014976
369 30-04-2010  0.106457377 5w  1.026629717 1.101014976
370 30-04-2010  0.022462141 5w  1.026629717 1.101014976
```

Comment: peho15ae, is it safe to assume that my answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60889293) was sufficient?

Comment: where is the data? please add it. you may use `dput(CombData)` and paste the output.

Comment: Sathish, I think the last column is the part peho15ae needs based on the first four columns (that are the raw data).

Comment: @r2evans I thought it is the expected output. Sorry about that ...

Comment: Yes, @r2evans your code worked superbly. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't understand why you are expecting anything other than 1.05 and 1.026 for the last two groups. Using the last, `1+mean(CombData$ExRet[19:23])` is 1.02663, not 1.10. Perhaps it's the cumulative part ... it's meaningless, because `1+mean(...)` will return exactly one number, so `cumprod` on a single number changes nothing. It would help if you shared the manual walk-through to determine your expected values.

Comment: I want the cumulative return. That is I want 1.053187859 * 1.050524434 which equals 1.1064. Likewise I would want the second part to equal 1.101 because 1.072455783 * 1.026629717 is 1.101. I hope this makes sense